# Spoiler block image and tag and bug

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, markdown-rendering, spoilers

So in markdown the code `>!` makes a spoiler block.

Something like
`>! Hello` gives

> Hello

with a nice fade in/out effect.
However, when you insert an image or tag like `>! Hello [tag:bug]` it does not display correctly. Example:

> Hello this are bugs in StackExchange: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

The tag does not hide itself when the mouse is on top of the block. Same for images. Example:

```
 >! This is a picture of Jeff Atwood: ![Jeff Atwood][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l9vY.png
```

Gives :

> This is a picture of Jeff Atwood:
>  [image: Jeff Atwood].

The text still fades in/out but the image does not. For the tag, the text fades in/out but the border does not and the text color changed from the background color of the block to green.

On older sites like [GameDev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/64731/thecodingmonster), you get [image: this].
 The text "eyeballcode" is in the tilder notation thing inside a spoiler. Also, there is no fade in/out effect.

Comment: The image disappears on my end. It pops in and out. It's funny because they do it at different rates. The image pops in first and the text after, and then the image disappears first, followed by the text.  It's like the Cheshire Cat leaving his smile behind.

Comment: I also mentioned the picture bug, which is very weird. So it is not really a dupe

Comment: But the image does disappear. For me, anyway. It doesn't **fade** but it's not visible.

Comment: It just goes away instantly like *Poof!* while the text slowly fades away